# WP Bakery Customization

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, vertical-alignment, wpbakery

Using WP Bakery, I'd like assistance with customising content within and equal height column.

I'd like to justify content within columns to have the top most content at the top of its column and the bottom most content at the bottom of its column. at the same time id like to have the columns be equal height.

To make them equal height, I am currently using a class called `d-flex align-items-stretch`. This allows me to choose where the content align from vertically, bottom or top.

The example attached shows how the column heights can be equal, with content aligned from the bottom, but the additional space is being applied at the top. Id like the additional space to be filled in between the content.

For example Space-Between

Any ideas?